How to calculate the difference between quaternions
I have written some code in python. The orientation of different objects in the simulation are stored using quaternions. At one point I have some orientation q and another orientation q'. I need to find the quaternion which represents the rotation, r from q to q'. My simulation has a function for this r = getDifferenceQuaternion(q, q')   # from q to q'.
The code works so I know this is the right method. The issue is I want to formalise what this function does in a report. For reasons that escape me the source code of my simulation (pybullet) seems impossible to find so I do not know what this function is doing on the inside.
I believe I understand applying rotations using quaternions. In that to rotate orientation quaternion q by the rotation quaternion r, I do q' = rqr^-1 with the multiplications left to right and following the rules of how i,j and k interact. I understand that multiplication is just like multiplying complex numbers, but now just with more parts.
So my problem boils down to given that q' = rqr^-1, r is some rotation which rotates q to q', how can I solve for r if I only know q and q'?
What im trying to do in my report (which doesn't focus on quaternions but needs some background on them so the rest makes sense) is define some nicer operations so I can sort of hide away the maths for the reader. I have defined a sort of 'adding rotations' [+] which is just applying the rotation to another quaternion q [+] r = rqr^-1. I now want to define 'subtracting rotations' [-] in the sense of finding the difference between two rotations (not undoing a rotation, that would be q [+] r^-1 = r^-1qr). I want r = q' [-] q such that q [+] r = q'
Many thanks for any help, I've been wracking my brain on this for a few days

When I'm in your situation, the first thing I wonder is whether I'm the first person, or if someone else has been there and solved this problem before. And there are libraries written for working with quaternions in python. pyquaternion seems to have some of the methods you are thinking about.

I am using libraries for all this. I mentioned in the post that I am trying to understand the underlying maths for the report accompanying my code. The code is working so thats not the issue, its just it all uses named functions like getDifferenceQuaternion which are a black box to me.

The fact that you have a function getDifferenceQuaternion which (a) doesn't follow PEP8 and (b) returns the quotient of the quaternions instead of the difference, makes me think whoever wrote the library doesn't know much about python libraries or quaternions. This is why I suggested a better library, which might have been written by someone who knows the math better too.


to rotate orientation quaternion q by the rotation quaternion r, I do q' = rqr^-1

This is incorrect. The correct method is $q' = rq$. This is because quaternions rotate vectors $v$ (represented as imaginary quaternions) via $qvq^{-1}$, so the composition of two rotations is $rqvq^{-1}r^{-1} = (rq)v(rq)^{-1}$ and we can see that $r$ and $q$ combine as $rq$.
The "difference" between quaternions that you seek is then simply $$\mathtt{getDifferenceQuaternion}(q,q') = q'q^{-1},$$ as you can see: $$(rq)q^{-1} = r.$$

So to rotate a vector (x,y,z) by r I make p=0 + xi + yj + zk and do rpr^-1, but if q is a rotation then to compose rotations you just do rq? Why is it different, is there any intuition behind that. The simulation definitely returns orientation as a quaternion not a 3 vector. I will do some investigating, maybe w is always 0 in which case they are secretly just vectors. But I understood it as the orientation of the object is the rotation which goes from its start orientation to its current one. Hence it is a rotation not a vector.

@rotatedBananna Yes, that's right, and I gave you the reason. You transform a vector $v$ to $v'$ with $q$ via $v' = qvq^{-1}$. Now if we transform $v'$ to $v''$ with $r$ we do $$v''=rv'r^{-1} = rqvq^{-1}r^{-1} = (rq)v(rq)^{-1}.$$ You can see here that, just thinking about how vectors transform, we necessarily compose quaternions using just multiplication $rq$.

@rotatedBananna An orientation quaternion $q$ represents a rotation from a previously agreed upon reference frame. For example, if our reference is the standard $x,y,z$ frame represented by imaginary quaternions $i,j,k$, then the frame $q$ represents is $$qiq^{-1},\quad qjq^{-1},\quad qkq^{-1}.$$ It is very unlikely that the $w$-component of $q$ is zero; this corresponds to a $180^\circ$ rotation.

I see, my confusion was stemming from how the simulation deals with orientations but I understand now thankyou. I have verified with code how it actually works now. "An orientation quaternion q represents a rotation from a previously agreed upon reference frame". This is exactly right. The orientation of objects is the rotation which takes them from the starting orientation to were they are now. It is not a vector encoding which way it currently faces. For this reason, to rotate an object we compose the rotation with its previous orientation, ie rq as you said. Thanks for your help
